# Mouse click addEventListener not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

[image]Here is my code:

```
    package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.geom.*;
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;

    import Game.*;

    public class GameController extends MovieClip
    {
        private var player:Jovia;
        private var speed:Number;
        private var gravity:Number;
        private var randomChance:Number;
        private var randomChance1:Number;
        private var ungos:Array;
        private var apples:Array;
        private var score:Number;       

        public function GameController()
        {

        }

        public function startMenu()
        {
            btnPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoGame);
            btnHelp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoHowToPlay);
            btnCredits.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoCredits);
        }

        public function startGhost()
        {

        }

        public function startHelp()
        {
            btnPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoGame);
        }

        public function startCredits()
        {
            btnPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoGame);
        }

        public function startGameOver()
        {

            gotoAndStop("gameOver");
            txtScore.text = String(score);
            btnPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoGame);
            gravity = C.GRAVITY;
            speed = C.PLAYER_SPEED;
        }

        private function gotoCredits(evt:MouseEvent)
        {
            btnPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoGame);
            btnHelp.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoHowToPlay);
            btnCredits.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoCredits);
            gotoAndStop("credits");
        }

        private function gotoHowToPlay(evt:MouseEvent)
        {
            btnPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoGame);
            btnHelp.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoHowToPlay);
            btnCredits.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoCredits);
            gotoAndStop("howtoplay");
        }

        private function gotoGame(evt:MouseEvent)
        {
            btnPlay.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoGame);
            btnHelp.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoHowToPlay);
            btnCredits.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoCredits);
            gotoAndStop("game");
        }

        public function startGame()
        {
            speed = C.PLAYER_SPEED;
            gravity = C.GRAVITY;
            score = C.PLAYER_START_SCORE;
            randomChance = C.APPLE_SPAWN_CHANCE;
            randomChance1 = C.UNGO_SPAWN_CHANCE;
            ungos = new Array();
            apples = new Array();
            player = new Jovia();
            mcGameStage.addChild(player);           
            mcGameStage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
        }       

        private function update(evt:Event)
        {
            //******************            
            //Handle User Input
            //******************
            var currMouseX = mouseX;
            var currMouseY = mouseY;
            var moveX = 0;
            var moveY = 0;
            if (currMouseX > player.x)
            {
                moveX = 1;
            }
            else if (currMouseX < player.x)
            {
                moveX = -1;
            }
            if (currMouseY > player.y)
            {
                moveY = 1;              
            }
            else if (currMouseY < player.y)
            {
                moveY = -1;             
            }           

            //******************
            //Handle Game Logic
            //******************
            //Handle new Player Position
            if (moveX > 0)
            {
                if (player.x + C.PLAYER_SPEED <= currMouseX)
                    player.x += C.PLAYER_SPEED;
            }
            else if (moveX < 0)
            {
                if (player.x - C.PLAYER_SPEED > currMouseX)
                    player.x -= C.PLAYER_SPEED;
            }           
            if (moveY > 0)
            {
                if (player.y + C.PLAYER_SPEED <= currMouseY)
                    player.y += C.PLAYER_SPEED;
            }
            else if (moveY < 0)
            {
                if (player.y - C.PLAYER_SPEED > currMouseY)
                    player.y -= C.PLAYER_SPEED; 
            }
            //Spawn Ungo
            if (Math.random() < randomChance1)
            {
                var newUngo = new Ungo();
                newUngo.x = Math.random() * C.UNGO_SPAWN_END_X + C.UNGO_SPAWN_START_X;

                newUngo.y = C.UNGO_START_Y;
                ungos.push(newUngo);

                mcGameStage.addChildAt(newUngo,0);
            }
            //Move Ungo
            for (var i = ungos.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                ungos[i].y += gravity;

                if (ungos[i].y > C.UNGO_END_Y)
                {
                    mcGameStage.removeChild(ungos[i]);
                    ungos.splice(i,1);
                }
            }   



            //Spawn new apples
            if (Math.random() < randomChance)
            {
                var newApple = new Apple();
                newApple.x = Math.random() * C.APPLE_SPAWN_END_X + C.APPLE_SPAWN_START_X;

                newApple.y = C.APPLE_START_Y;
                apples.push(newApple);

                mcGameStage.addChildAt(newApple,0);
            }           
            //Move Apples
            for (var i = apples.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                apples[i].y += gravity;

                if (apples[i].y > C.APPLE_END_Y)
                {
                    mcGameStage.removeChild(apples[i]);
                    apples.splice(i,1);
                }
            }           

            //Check for collision
            var playerPoint = new Point(player.x, player.y);
            for (var i = apples.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var applePoint:Point = new Point(apples[i].x, apples[i].y);
                if (Point.distance(applePoint,playerPoint) < C.HIT_TOLERANCE)
                {
                    //Register hit
                    score += C.SCORE_PER_APPLE;

                    mcGameStage.removeChild(apples[i]);
                    apples.splice(i,1);
                }
            }
            //ungo collision
            for (var i = ungos.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var ungoPoint:Point = new Point(ungos[i].x, ungos[i].y);
                if (Point.distance(ungoPoint,playerPoint) < C.HIT_TOLERANCE)
                {
                    //Register hit

                    mcGameStage.removeChild(ungos[i]);
                    ungos.splice(i,1);
                    gotoAndStop("ghost");
                }
            }

            //******************
            //Handle Display
            //******************
            //Animate the player
            if (moveX > 0)
            {
                if (player.currentLabel != C.JOVIA_RIGHT)
                    player.gotoAndPlay(C.JOVIA_RIGHT);
            }
            else if (moveX < 0)
            {
                if (player.currentLabel != C.JOVIA_LEFT)
                    player.gotoAndPlay(C.JOVIA_LEFT);
            }           
            //Display new Score
            txtScore.text = String(score);
        }
    }
}
```

Code per frames:

Menu:

```
stop();
startMenu();
```

Game:

```
stop();
startGame();
```

gameOver:

```
stop();
startGameOver();
```

howtoplay:

```
stop();
startHelp();
```

Credits:

```
stop();
startCredits();
```

Ghost:

```
stop();
var snd_scream = new SoundScream();
snd_scream.play();
    var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(2000, 1);
    myTimer.start();
    myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, function(e:TimerEvent){
       startGameOver();
    });
```

The problem here is that on function `startMenu()`, all the buttons are working as expected, but on my function `startHelp()` the button does not react at all. What could I have done wrong here? Can anyone point it out? Buttons also are not working for `startCredits()`, and `startGameOver()`.

Comment: Can you ensure that the basics are valid? i.e. button instance, frame name...

Comment: yes the instances are valid, they were working a few hours ago though, not sure what i did, is there anyway for me to check if the  the event was triggered?

Comment: When are the functions `startHelp`, `startCredits` and `startGameOver` called?

Comment: @Pimgd they are respectively called when their equivalent Action Script frames are triggered, i have 5 frame menus: menu, game, gameOver, howtoplay, credits

each has the actionscript to call the equivalent functions

Comment: And do your button instances exist on each of those frames? A script on frame 5 can't alter the properties of an object on frame 1... at least not without doing some magic.

Comment: @Pimgd yes, the only code on those frames are stop(), and function call. though how would i be able to check if the button is pressed? could this also be a result of me not being able to remove the listener properly?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the complete code per frame that has code?

Comment: @Pimgd will do, give me a sec. btw how do i check if all my instances are correct?

Comment: `trace("instancename exists? "+ (instancename != undefined))` should do the trick.

Comment: @Pimgd where should i place that? thank you also updated my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63117/discussion-between-pimgd-and-magicianiam). (<- link to join me in chat, you can click it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by removing all the removeEventListener and by removing the addEventListener in functions gotoCredits, and gotoHowToPlay. But is this a proper way of doing things, since when you add a listener shouldn't you remove them also?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using the correct frame names? you refer to them with capital letters yet they are lowercased in your code. Does code on your frames even get called? You should check on it by inserting some `trace()` statements

Comment: @MartonPallagi sorry about that, the correct spelling of the names are the ones being called not the one i wrote as label. you can also see it at the image above :)